Text Replacement in Snowflake
select 
    'This (is) a-Test' as subject,
    'This (is) a-' as pattern,
    regexp_replace(subject,pattern,'',1,1);

In the above example, I am trying to replace the first occurrence of the pattern from the subject. I just want to extract Test from subject but I am getting This (is) a-Test. I cannot use escape characters ('This \\(is\\) a-Test') because in the real application both subject and pattern are coming from two columns.
My question is how to ignore brackets when using regexp_replace to replace string in snowflake?

If you don't need regular expressions syntax, just use replace():
select 
    'This (is) a-Test' as subject,
    'This (is) a-' as pattern,
    replace(subject,pattern)
    ;


Note that this will replace all occurrences, not just the first.
If you want to replace only the first, then:
select 
    'Oh This (is) a-Test' as subject,
    'This (is) a-' as pattern,
    position(pattern, subject) pos,
    iff(pos=0, subject, substr(subject, 1, pos-1) || substr(subject, pos + length(pattern)))
    ;


But replace is going to replace all occurrence of the pattern. I just want to replace the first occurrence.

answer updated for only the first

Using insert
set str = 'this is a-test; but this is a-test too';
set pat = 'this is a-';

select iff(contains($str,$pat), insert($str,charindex($pat,$str),len($pat),''), $str)

